How to handle null value in logic app condition module
I have a logic app where i use a condition expression on to two variables, displayName and accountName.
Sometimes a variable will not exist. which will cause this error:
InvalidTemplate
Unable to process template language expressions for action 'Condition' at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'contains' expects its first argument 'collection' to be a dictionary (object), an array or a string. The provided value is of type 'Null'.'.

How do i handle this error? I want the condition to treat the null value as if the variable is a empty string

Is it possible to write a expression thats like iff(accountName is empty(), '', accountname)?

You can use coalesce() function which checks if the variable contains null values and then it replaces with empty string in its place

stackoverflow post 38976744 : i see this coalesce example but i dont understand how to apply it here

Use like this coalesce(variables('accountName'),'')

You can do so by using coalesce() function.
I am using below given expressions to achieve this.
coalesce(variables('accountName'),'')
coalesce(variables('displayName'),'')


This works if one variable is not exist. Here I am only passing the value of account name but not display name.


Another method is to use the if expression:
if(equals(item()?['accountName'], null),'',item()?['accountName'])


